# multi value fetch in style tag in html php

Tags: php, jquery

```
<select name="organization" id="orgId" style="<?php echo $_POST['report_type'] == 'org_participation' ? '' : 'display:none'; ?>">
```

I have 3 values: `org_participation`, `monthly`, `daily`.

I have tried all three include in style like

```
<select name="organization" id="orgId" style="<?php echo $_POST['report_type'] == 'org_participation','monthly','daily' ? '' : 'display:none'; ?>">
```

But not get any result i know it wrong way but tried something like this.

Please help me to solve this issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```php
in_array($_POST['report_type'], ['org_participation', 'monthly', 'daily'])
```

to check whether `report_type` is one of `'org_participation', 'monthly', 'daily'`.

So

```
<select name="organization" id="orgId" style="<?php echo in_array($_POST['report_type'], ['org_participation', 'monthly', 'daily']) ? '' : 'display:none'; ?>">
```

Comment: ty so much it woked for me